# Spring best way to check result of @ModelAttribute annotated method

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I must check the returned result of a method which is annotated with @ModelAttribute in my handling method. I try something like that :

```
@RequestMapping("/test")
public class TestController{

  @ModelAttribute("object")
  public Integer getObj(){
   //return something
  }

  @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public String process(ModelMap model){
    if(model.get("object") == null)
      //something
    return "view";
  }
}
```

Is it correct way?

Comment: Does your code work ?

Comment: Yes but I want to make sure that it will not produce unexpected errors in future

Comment: You can use spring validators for the same. Refer the [link](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html)

Comment: How about writing a unit tests of this method to chcek if it behaves as expected.

Comment: Thanks for all advices